# How to crawl the result of another crawl in the same parse function?

Tags: recursion, scrapy, web-crawler

Hi so i am crawling a website with articles, within each article is a link to a file, i managed to crawl all the article links, now i want to access each one and collect the link within it, instead of maybe having to save the result of the first crawl to a json and then writting another script.

thing is i am new to scrapy so i dont really know how to do that, thanks in advance!

```
import scrapy

class SgbdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sgbd"

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.sante.gouv.sn/actualites/"
    ]

    def parse(self,response):

        base = "http://www.sante.gouv.sn/actualites/"

        for link in response.css(".card-title a"):
            title = link.css("a::text").get()

            href = link.css("a::attr(href)").extract()

#here instead of yield, i want to parse the href and then maybe yield the result of THAT parse.
            yield{
            "title" : title,
            "href" : href
            }

            # next step for each href, parse again and get link in that page for pdf file
            #   pdf link can easily be collected with response.css(".file a::attr(href)").get()
            #   then write that link in a json file
        next_page = response.css("li.pager-next a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None and next_page.split("?page=")[-1] != "35":
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page,callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can yield a request to those pdf link with a new callback where you will put the logic extracting

Answer (score 1):

- A crawl spider rather than the simple basic spider is better suited to handle this. The basic spider template is generated by default so you have to specify the template to use when generating the spider.
- Assuming you've created the project & are in the root folder:

  ```sh
  $ scrapy genspider -t crawl sgbd sante.sec.gouv.sn
  ```
- Opening up `sgbd.py` file, you'll notice the difference between it & the basic spider template.
- If you're unfamiliar with XPath, [here's a run-through](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)
- `LinkExtractor` & `Rule` will define your spider's behavior [as per the documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider)
- Edit the file:

  ```py
  import scrapy
  from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
  from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


  class SgbdSpider(CrawlSpider):
      name = 'sgbd'
      allowed_domains = ['sante.sec.gouv.sn']
      start_urls = ['https://sante.sec.gouv.sn/actualites']

      user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'

      def set_user_agent(self, request, spider):
          request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.user_agent
          return request

      # First rule get the links to the articles; callback is the function executed after following the link to each article
      # Second rule handles pagination
      # Couldn't get it to work when passing css selectors in LinkExtractor as restrict_css,
      # used XPaths instead
      rules = (
          Rule(
              LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[11]/a'), 
              callback='parse_item', 
              follow=True,
              process_request='set_user_agent',
          ),
          Rule(
              LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/span/div/h4/a'),
              process_request='set_user_agent',
          )
      )

      # Extract title & link to pdf
      def parse_item(self, response):
          yield {
              'title': response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/section/div[1]/div[1]/article/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/a/font/font/text()').get(),
              'href': response.xpath('//*[@id="main-content"]/section/div[1]/div[1]/article/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/a/@href').get()
          }
  ```
- Unfortunately this is as far as I could go as the site was inaccessible even with different proxies, it was taking too long to respond. You might have to tweak those XPaths a littler further. Better luck on your side.
- Run the spider & save output to json

  ```sh
  $ scrapy crawl sgbd -o results.json
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Parse links in another function. Then parse again in yet another function. You can yield whatever results you want in any of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @bens_ak47 & @user9958765 said, use a separate function.

For example, change this:

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

to this:

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_pdffile)
```

then add the new method:

```
def parse_pdffile(self, response):
    print(response.url)
```